# mySQL update multiple rows with the same value

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a `files` table

`(userID, fileID, fileName, folderID, folderName).`

i want to update multiple rows for a user where duplicates are found such as

currently, I have `userID=1` who has `2 files` both under the `folderName`of `'work'` and `folderID of '1'`,

i want to update the folderName to `'work1'` but keep the same `folderID of '1'`.

this is my current sql statement and i can't get it to work:

```
UPDATE files SET fileFolder = '$folderName'  
WHERE folderID = '$folderID' AND userID = '$userID'
```

Comment: please explain what you mean by it doesn't work, error message, etc.

Comment: not clear !! can you show a demo values of you table

Comment: @Andrew-OpenGeoCode the sql query is not carried out. it doesn't do anything in regards to the data that i want to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE files SET fileFolder = '$folderName'  
WHERE folderID = '$folderID' AND userID = '$userID'
```

instead of setting fileFolder, did you try using folderName ? such as ..

```
UPDATE files SET folderName= '$folderName'  
WHERE folderID = '$folderID' AND userID = '$userID'
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to update folder name e.g work to work1 if work folder has more than one time. so you need ti check if old folder has more than once.

Try something like this( not tested):

```
  UPDATE files SET folderName= '$folderName'  
    WHERE folderID = '$folderID' AND userID = '$userID' AND ( 1 < (SELECT count(*) from files where folderID = $folderID and folderName='oldFolderName'))
```